# Resource usage of kubelet when writing pod logs

Tags: performance, kubernetes, logging, kubelet

Does letting the kubelet write logs that pods emit on their stdout / stderr consume more resources such as CPU and memory, than if the pods wrote their logs directly to a mounted volume? I am asking this considering that the logs are copied from the pod to the kubelet across processes. Or does the disk IO by N pods instead of one kubelet offset any advantage?

I recognize that not letting kubelet handle the logs means `kubectl logs ...` would not show recent logs. But otherwise, could there be performance advantage to not writing through an intermediary like kubelet?

Comment: You can [configure log verbosity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-logs/) to see more or less detail. Logs can be as coarse-grained as showing errors within a component, or as fine-grained as showing step-by-step traces of events (like HTTP access logs, pod state changes, controller actions, or scheduler decisions.

Comment: That's a completely orthogonal point to the question asked. For a given verbosity, what's the difference in resource usage between the kubelet writing the logs to didi vs the pods themselves doing it - that is the question being asked.

Comment: Kubernetes cluster components that run in pods, these write to files inside the /var/log directory, bypassing the default logging mechanism (the components do not write to the systemd journal). You can use Kubernetes' storage mechanisms to map persistent storage into the container that runs the component. See [Cluster-level logging architectures](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#cluster-level-logging-architectures) for more info.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy this isn't helpful because it is not related to the question asked.